# working on project Euler Q 1 wondering if there is a way to store my for if loop result into an array

Tags: javascript

Here is what I have so far:

```
 var i = 1;

for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i++ )
if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) 
{
  console.log(i);
 }
```

Is there a way to get all the values of i from my loop into an array for me to add together?
I can get the loop to run to get all the numbers to match, just haven't been able to store the values.

Thanks for any help.
Or does

Comment: Hi I did some more research and figured out what else was wrong with this code.
I don't want to give out the answer but if any other people find this question.
You don't need to define i because it's being used a temporary variable that will only exist within the loop.
Create another variable and make it = 0
the console.log is outside of the brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array and call `Array.prototype.push()` chained to variable array with `i` as parameter, or add  `i` values using `+=` operator, or both.

```js
var i = 1;
var arr = Array();
var sum = 0;

for (; i < 1000; i++) 
  if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
    arr.push(i);
    sum += i;
  }
  
console.log("arr:", arr, "\nsum:", sum);
```